# Issue in passing Partitioner ExecutionContext to reader

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to achieve a simple thing - to convert xml based partitioner job to annotations.

Stuck in this part ,

```
<bean id="pagingItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
        scope="step">


        <property name="parameterValues">
            <map>
                <entry key="minId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[minId]}" />
                <entry key="maxId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[maxId]}" />
            </map>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Corresponding annotation code is like ,

```
@Bean
    public Step masterStep(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
                .partitioner(slaveStep(syncReader(null,null),writer(),processor()))
                .partitioner("slaveStep", rangePartitioner)
                .gridSize(10)
                .taskExecutor(simpleAsyntaskExecutor)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name="slaveStep")
    public Step slaveStep(
            ItemReader<RemittanceVO> syncReader, ItemWriter<RemittanceClaimVO> writer,
            ItemProcessor<RemittanceVO, RemittanceClaimVO> processor) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
                .<RemittanceVO, RemittanceClaimVO> chunk(Constants.SPRING_BATCH_CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(syncReader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Partitioner rangePartitioner(){
        RangePartitioner rangePartitioner = new RangePartitioner();
        return rangePartitioner;
    }

@Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<RemittanceVO> syncReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[minId]}") Long minId,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[maxId]}") Long maxId) {
        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<RemittanceVO> syncReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<RemittanceVO>();
        syncReader.setDelegate(reader(minId,maxId));
        return syncReader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamReader<RemittanceVO> reader(Long minId,Long maxId) {
        JdbcPagingItemReader<RemittanceVO> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<RemittanceVO>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new RemittanceRowMapper());
        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
        reader.setPageSize(Constants.SPRING_BATCH_READER_PAGE_SIZE);
        Map<String,Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        if(minId !=null) parameterValues.put("minId", minId);
        if(maxId !=null) parameterValues.put("maxId", maxId);
        reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<RemittanceVO, RemittanceClaimVO> processor() {
        return new MatchClaimProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<RemittanceClaimVO> writer() {
        return new MatchedClaimWriter();
    }
```

I get this error with this code which seems like `Long` dependency was not satisfied ,

```
35307 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-6] ERROR - 2016-09-06 12:23:48.692; org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep; Encountered an error executing step slaveStep in job runPartitionerJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.reader' defined in class path resource [com/hmsy/bp/config/AppConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reader' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Long] found for dependency [java.lang.Long]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Long] found for dependency [java.lang.Long]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader.read(SynchronizedItemStreamReader.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:268)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Long] found for dependency [java.lang.Long]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 47 more
35307 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-11] ERROR - 2016-09-06 12:23:48.692; org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep; Encountered an error executing step slaveStep in job runPartitionerJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.reader' defined in class path resource [com/hmsy/bp/config/AppConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reader' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Long] found for dependency [java.lang.Long]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Long] found for dependency [java.lang.Long]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader.read(SynchronizedItemStreamReader.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:268)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.Long] found for dependency [java.lang.Long]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 47 more
```

As done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233597/spring-batch-annotation-partitioner-issue), I pass `null` from `masterStep` . `masterStep` bean is created successfully and error occurs while trying to execute `masterStep`.

XML code works without any issues. I have shown only partial xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve issue by moving non - synchronized reader code to synchronized decorator code. Somehow, calling & passing parameters to non-synchronized reader from synchronized reader didn't worked.

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<RemittanceVO> syncReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[minId]}") Long minId,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[maxId]}") Long maxId) throws Exception{
        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<RemittanceVO> syncReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<RemittanceVO>();
        Map<String,Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        if(minId !=null && minId.longValue() !=0)  parameterValues.put("minId", minId);
        if(maxId !=null && maxId.longValue() !=0) parameterValues.put("maxId", maxId);
        JdbcPagingItemReader<RemittanceVO> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<RemittanceVO>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new RemittanceRowMapper());
        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
        reader.setPageSize(Constants.SPRING_BATCH_READER_PAGE_SIZE);
        reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        syncReader.setDelegate(reader);
        return syncReader;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a synchronized reader? That will eliminate the ability to multi-thread your partitioned steps.

Comment: I am new to batch API, don't know most of the things in detail. On answer to one of my [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199182/mark-read-data-as-processing-by-a-table-column-flag-then-restore-at-the-end), it was suggested to use that but that was not in partitioning context.

Comment: As long as your reader is in step scope (which it will have to be in order to access the step execution context), then you'll have one instance per step (and consequently one instance thread per thread). Assuming the reader isn't manipulating static properties, having one instance per thread will guarantee that you're "thread-safe". Synchronizing in that scenario would dramatically slow you down without any benefit.